# JavaScript module pattern: default values

Tags: javascript, module, design-patterns

I'm working on a project where we use a pattern to define "modules" (i.e. effectively public static classes), where each module has an `init()` that should be called once the module has been defined. It looks like:

```
MyNamespace.MyModule = (function () {
    var my = {};
    my.init = function(config) {
        // setup initial state using config
    };
    return my;
})();
```

I'm seeing two patterns in this code base for defining `config` defaults and wondering which one might be better—if there's any advantage or disadvantage that I'm not immediately seeing. Recommendations?

Here's the first:

```
MyNamespace.MyModule = (function () {
    var my = {}, 
        username,
        policyId,
        displayRows;

    my.init = function(config) {
        config = config || {};
        username = config.username || 'Anonymous';
        policyId = config.policyId || null;
        displayRows = config.displayRows || 50;
    };

    return my;
})();
```

And here's the second:

```
MyNamespace.MyModule = (function () {
    var my = {}, 
        username = 'Anonymous',
        policyId = null,
        displayRows = 50;

    my.init = function(config) {
        config = config || {};
        username = config.username || username;
        policyId = config.policyId || policyId;
        displayRows = config.displayRows || displayRows;
    };

    return my;
})();
```

Comment: The second example follows best practices by initializing your members and then using their default values as the defaults if nothing is supplied in the config.

Comment: The second variant is also better if default parameters can contain complex objects as subparameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't much of a difference, it's really all about what's readable to you.  I personally like the 2nd method because it separates the defaults from the logic.